# How to solve ref reading undefined in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am developing a `React Native` app, and I needed to have a listener in `Keyboard` and each time it's opened I scroll to the end of the page.

I implemented this mechanism like this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this._scrollView = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
 this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
}

 componentWillUnmount() {
  this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
  this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
 }

 _keyboardDidShow() {
   console.log(this._scrollView)
   //this._scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
 }

_keyboardDidHide() {
}

//Render
 <Animated.ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    ref={(scrollView) => { this._scrollView = scrollView; }}
 >
```

But no matter what I've tried `_scrollView` ref inside `_keyboardDidShow` is undefined

I tried console logging the ref in a `Button` click and it's reading fine

How do I solve this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to bind the listeners in order for it to work.